# Best path in vectorfield

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, vector-analysis, variational-analysis

Consider a vectorfield on the surface of a sphere, which is a (continuously differentiable) function representing the wind on earth. Now, let's say I want to calculate the path of an airplane such that the path minimizes its fuel consumption.

So, I am looking for a function minimizing a functional. The functional is basically the fuel cost of the path, so the time it takes to fly the path times some constant. It sounds to me as a problem where the Euler-Lagrange equations are usable, but after a quick try the equations tend to become extremely difficult (like in more then 3 pages long).

Is there some way to avoid these difficulties? The usage of numerical methods is also perfectly fine.

Comment: It's not many details here. For example what is the functional you have?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Ok, but adding that sentence does not improve the question imo. It's still no details here. I don't know what the difficulties you are having is so I don't know how to answer how you can avoid them (just saying "it becomes extremely difficult" tells us nothing). In general deriving the EL equations and then solving them numerically (I doubt such a problem has analytical solutions) would be the "standard" method here...

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equations would be an "indirect" approach to the problem in the sense that you're solving the optimization analytically to get a necessary set of ODE's and then numerically solving said ODEs. There are, in contrast, "direct methods", where the original functional minimization problem is completely discretized and solved via numerical optimization (think gradient descent). Check out [this wiki article on trajectory optimization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_optimization?wprov=sfla1). I think your question is too broad for a specific answer.

Comment: Show us at least one page of your previous work.